# How to add dropdown menu support to Beez template?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I need dropdown menu support to Beez template? Can it be done? The other default template (protostart) already has support for dropdown menus but it sucks: it is very difficult to click a sub-menu, it simply disappear if you don't position the mouse properly.

Comment: Either custom code it, use an extension, or use a different template. [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=joomla+beez3+dropdown+menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to an extension in JED

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ari-ext-menu

its a simple drop down menu which is very easily styled, i have used it a number of times.